# Simple Enclosed Custom loss function not working

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I was trying to implement a custom loss function. so i first tried to make a custom function by directly enclosing of one of the default keras loss functions. `tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentrophy`

but it didn't work.
How could this be possible??? I have worked with custom functions in the past and just today this shocked me.
Why isn't it working? how can I make this simple function work?

```
@tf.function
def sameloss(y_true, y_pred):
    output = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    return output
```

I compile it using
`model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(), loss=sameloss)`

during training the loss just gets stuck at 10, and not moving.
but when I set the loss directly to `loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy` during compilation it works well and the loss flyes to zero. but stops working when I set it to the same loss function enclosed in my custom `sameloss` function as `loss=sameloss`

Comment: Can you share the statement you use to compile the model?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to execute your custom loss function in TF 2.4, please refer working code as shown below

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

@tf.function
def sameloss(y_true, y_pred):
    output = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    return output

input = np.random.rand(1000,15)
labels = np.random.rand(1000,15)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(15))
model.compile(optimizer='RMSprop', loss=sameloss)

model.fit(input, labels, epochs=5)
```

Output:

```
2.4.1
Epoch 1/5
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 48.8549
Epoch 2/5
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 976us/step - loss: 43.7030
Epoch 3/5
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 39.2598
Epoch 4/5
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 37.5566
Epoch 5/5
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 34.7458
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f11f03b3fd0>
```